# Panels default content when creating a new page

Tags: panels, theming

When I'm creating a new panel page within the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module I want the new page to automatically load up with the content and layout and settings of my default site template.

For example, I want the site name, logo, main menu and a few other things to show on every single page without manually adding it every time I create a new page.

Should I not be creating a new Panel page for each section of my site?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new page by *cloning* (AKA copying) the one you've already made with all your content/layout/settings chosen.

Under `admin/structure/pages`, navigate to the `Edit` form for the page you've already created and would like to replicate (See screenshot).

[image]

Then, click on the Clone button on the top, right-hand menu of the page's Edit form (See screenshot).

[image: Click the Clone button]

Then just follow the wizard's instructions for cloning the page. Once you've cloned the page, you'll have a brand new page with all the same content, layout, and settings as the previous one.